# Trying to access dot notation variable with a string

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on creating a web form that can dynamically read a swagger endpoint to create form fields.  Specifically right now I am trying to read the schemas from the component section defined by openAPI 3.

Example json:

```
{
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    .......
  },
  "paths": {
    ........
  },
  "components": {
    "schemas": {
      "FakeAppConfiguration": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "setting1": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "setting2": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
      },
      "OtherFakeAppConfiguration": {
        ........
      },
      "ThirdFakeAppConfiguration": {
        ........
      }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using this snippet of json as an example, I can easily get the names of the schemas that are defined by using (json has already been loaded into data using fetch)

```
for (let schema in data.components.schemas)
{
    //this will print out FakeAppConfiguration, OtherFakeAppConfiguration, ThirdFakeAppConfiguration
    console.log(schema);
}
```

My problem now comes in trying to access each of these schema trees without calling them directly.  I could easily do data.components.schemas.FakeAppConfiguration, but that would defeat the purpose of making this dynamic.  I've been trying to somehow use the strings obtained in the above loop to access what I want to no avail.  Some examples of things I've tried are below.  Anyone able to help me get further access without calling the variable directly with dot notation?  I have also considered doing manual parsing of the JSON, but trying to avoid that.  This is a react app, so if anyone can think of a library that could help, I'm all ears there as well.

```
//treating like a key
data.components.schemas['FakeAppConfiguration']




//trying to create a map
interface SchemaDef {
    type: string,
    properties: Properties,
    //....etc,etc
}

let i = 0;
let schemas: Map<string, SchemaDef> = new Map<string, SchemaDef>();

for (let schema in data.components.schemas)
{
    schemas.set(schema, data.components.schemas[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: `data.components.schemas` is an object, not an array, so `data.components.schemas[i]` (where `i` is a number) won't do anything. You have to fetch them by name *and you already have the names* - it's the `schema` variable. So, just grab them using `data.components.schemas[schema]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate over the `Object.entries()` of your "schemas" object.

```js
let schemas = {
      "FakeAppConfiguration": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "setting1": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "setting2": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
      },
     "FakeAppConfiguration2": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "setting1": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          },
          "setting2": {
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true
          }
        },
      }

    };
      
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(schemas)) {
    console.log(key, "\n\n", value);
}
```